# Displaying a background image on webpage behind existing content with CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Hi I have a system developed with PHP and CSS.

I wish to have background images that will cover the full screen of each page. However with my existing setup the image covers the other content on screen. I have tried this with my homepage initially. I created an img tag (Learning) in my php file on line 19 as shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT E-Learning Portal</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="images/Learning.jpg" id= "Learning" alt="">
<br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<center>
<h1> Select an E-Learning Module<h1>
<br>
<table align="center" height="200" width="40%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><button name="Surface" onclick="window.location.href='SurfaceExecute.php'">Surface Pro Basic Skills</button></td>
</tr>
<td><button name="eNISAT" onclick="window.location.href='eNISATExecute.php'">eNISAT Tutorials</button></td>
</tr>
<td><button name="Email" onclick="window.location.href='EmailExecute.php'">Email Tutorials</button></td>
</tr>
<td><button name="Policies" onclick="window.location.href='Policyview.php'">Policies and Procedures</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I then added the following CSS to my style.css file

```
/* css for home page  */
#Learning {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -20; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

My question is, how do I display this image in the background with existing screen content on top? Or is there a way to make the background image opaque so that the other content can be seen through it and clicked?

**UPDATE Solution found from the answer provided. Removed img tag from php file and updated CSS to the following**

```
html { 
  background: url(images/Learning.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the background-image property in CSS.
If you are doing that for the whole page, you might as well use it on the body element :

```
body {
   background-image : ........;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Guillaume Giraudon. Would I just use this body in addition to my original code? I am not that familar with CSS

Comment: Got it working with your answer @Guillaume Giraudon. I have updated my question. Removed the img tag from the php file and changed the CSS as shown in the question